# How can I use a PhoneGap plugin that is no longer supported?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am using this plugin to check if GPS is `enabled` or `disabled`:

https://github.com/fastrde/cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps

But when compiling the app it says that the plugin is no longer supported. How can I still use this code/plugin in the app? I am lost :(

Here is the error:

`Error - Plugin error (you probably need to remove plugin files from your app): Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps@1.0.0" via npm Installing "cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps" at "1.0.0" for android Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps': CordovaError: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.4.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-geolocation@^1.0.1".`

Or does anyone have any alternate suggestions?

Comment: Whats the exact error you get when compiling?

Comment: @David Error - Plugin error (you probably need to remove plugin files from your app): Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps@1.0.0" via npm Installing "cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps" at "1.0.0" for android Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps': CordovaError: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.4.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-geolocation@^1.0.1".

It's failing for both Android and iOS

Comment: Try deleting your `platforms` and `plugins` folders and then run `cordova platform add android`. You are seeing this error because the version of the geolocation plugin does not match the version (1.0.1) required by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Download the plugin from the repository as a zip.
2. Extract the zip.
3. Open the plugin.xml file that is located inside of the folder in your favorite text editor or IDE
4. Find this line `<dependency id="cordova-plugin-geolocation"version="1.0.1" />` and replace with this `<dependency id="cordova-plugin-geolocation"/>`
5. Now, install the plugin. The path should be the same folder that extracted.
   cordova plugin add C:\User\Desktop\cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps-master